# HTTP 502/404 with Grafana in Kubernetes, using AGIC

Tags: azure, kubernetes, grafana, helm, azure-application-gateway

I'm trying to deploy Grafana in Azure Kubernetes service (AKS), through Helm. I'm using the Helm charts provided by [Bitnami](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/grafana/). I've been following [this Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/tutorial-ingress-controller-add-on-existing) to set up the application gateway ingress controller.

The pods are running, and I have a `ClusterIP` service in front of them:

```
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
my-grafana   ClusterIP   10.0.230.64   <none>        3000/TCP   29m
```

Output of `kubectl describe svc`:

```
Name:              my-grafana
Namespace:         default
Labels:            app.kubernetes.io/component=grafana
                   app.kubernetes.io/instance=my-grafana
                   app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                   app.kubernetes.io/name=grafana
                   helm.sh/chart=grafana-8.4.5
Annotations:       meta.helm.sh/release-name: my-grafana
                   meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
                   service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: true
Selector:          app.kubernetes.io/component=grafana,app.kubernetes.io/instance=my-grafana,app.kubernetes.io/name=grafana
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.0.168.200
IPs:               10.0.168.200
Port:              http  3000/TCP
TargetPort:        dashboard/TCP
Endpoints:         10.244.0.20:3000,10.244.0.21:3000
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Next, I also have an ingress defined, which automatically configures the Application Gateway (AGW) using AGIC (AGW and AKS cluster are defined in the same resource group).

```
NAME         CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS         PORTS   AGE
my-grafana   <none>   *       52.XXX.XXX.XXX   80      29m
```

Output of `kubectl describe ing`:

```
Name:             my-grafana
Labels:           app.kubernetes.io/component=grafana
                  app.kubernetes.io/instance=my-grafana
                  app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                  app.kubernetes.io/name=grafana
                  helm.sh/chart=grafana-8.4.5
Namespace:        default
Address:          52.XXX.XXX.XXX
Ingress Class:    <none>
Default backend:  <default>
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *
              /*   my-grafana:http (10.244.0.16:3000,10.244.0.17:3000)
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
              meta.helm.sh/release-name: my-grafana
              meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
Events:
  Type     Reason               Age                From                       Message
  ----     ------               ----               ----                       -------
  Warning  PortResolutionError  31m (x2 over 32m)  azure/application-gateway  Code="ErrorServiceResolvedToInvalidPort" Message="service default/my-grafana and service port http was resolved to an invalid service-backend port 65536, defaulting to port 80"
```

If I try to connect to the external address (public IP attached to the AGW), I get an HTTP 502 error with the above configuration.

If I change `hostname: "*"` to `hostname: grafana.local` in the `values.yaml` file, the public IP now returns an HTTP 404 error instead.

When I'm connected to one of the pods, I can connect to Grafana using the cluster IP as well as each pod individually, on port 3000.

As far as I can tell, the issue is between the AGW and the Ingress/Service, but I have no idea what to investigate further. Any hints would be very much appreciated!